# How to scan from my HP-1610 (all in one) networked printer/scanner (Lion)

Tags: macos, network, scanning

I have an HP-1610 all in one.  It's hooked up to my TimeCapsule as a networked printer.  Networked-printing works.  I'm on Lion (latest; 10.7.3 as of this writing.)  I'd like to scan a sheet from my printer and get it onto my desktop (or wherever.)

I tried opening Preview.app and `Import From Scanner -> Include networked devices`, but the scanner never shows up in the popup menu.

I tried "Share scanner" in sharing preferences.

Oddly, in Print & Scan preferences, there is no "scan" option.  I think that's the bit I'm missing.

Hints?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** In Print & Scan prefs, my instance of the printer for when it's hard-wired has Print/Scan tabs but, for the networked one (the same printer appears in the list 2x), there is no Scan, only Print.  Same thing when I open the print queues.

Comment: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01925005&tmp_track_link=ot_faqs/top_issues/it_it/c01925005/loc:1&cc=it&dlc=it&lang=it&lc=it&product=306888&task=#N194

Answer (score 1):

Use Image Capture (Applications>Image Capture). Select the printer from the sidebar:
[image: image capture]

Comment: Thanks, but no-joy.  See edit-comment at end of question.  Yes, for the hard-wired version of this printer, I get those tabs.  No tabs for networked printer.

Comment: @Olie Edited answer again...

Comment: As with previous edit: scanner does not show in sidebar of ImageCapture.  I'm pretty sure that the problem is that Lion doesn't know that my HP-1610 can scan or, for some other reason, my scanner isn't shared.  Obviously, your Epson works as expected.  I believe my problem is at a lower level, though.

Comment: @Olie That is odd. Try removing, then re adding the printer. That fixes most problems for me.

Comment: Hmm, nope, sorry.  I'll wait a couple of weeks to make sure it's not reported as terribly broken, then try on Mountain Lion.  Maybe it's a 1610 driver thing.

Comment: Weird. Lemme know how it goes.